# discord.js v13 minecraft-server-util assertion error when getting the option of port

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am currently making a Minecraft server checker command using minecraft-server-util but everytime I enter the port number in the port option, the error `AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Expected 'port' to be a 'number', got 'object'` comes out. I am currently using the new interaction thing in discord.js v13.

Code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');
const util = require('minecraft-server-util');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('minecraft')
        .setDescription('Checks the status of a minecraft server.')
        .addStringOption(option => option.setName('address').setDescription('Enter the server address.').setRequired(true))
        .addNumberOption(option => option.setName('port').setDescription('Enter the server port. (25565 IS THE DEFAULT PORT)').setRequired(true)),
    async execute(interaction, client, MessageEmbed) {
        let server = interaction.options.getString('address');
        let serverPort = interaction.options.getNumber('port');

        if(serverPort == NaN) return interaction.reply({ content: 'The server port you provided is not a number.', ephemeral: true });

        util.status(server, { port: parseInt(serverPort)}).then((response) => {
            var fav = response.favicon.split(",").slice(1).join(",");
            var imageStream = Buffer.from(fav, "base64");
            var attachment = new MessageAttachment(imageStream, "favicon.png");
            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#008000')
            .setTitle('Minecraft Server Status')
            .attachFiles([attachment])
            .addFields(
                {name: 'Server IP', value: response.host},
                {name: 'Online Players', value: response.onlinePlayers},
                {name: 'Player Threshold', value: response.maxPlayers},
                {name: 'MOTD', value: response.motd.clean},
                {name: 'Version', value: response.version},
            )
            .setThumbnail("attachment://favicon.png")
            interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] })
        })
        .catch ((error) => {
            interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error finding this server.', ephemeral: true });
            throw error;
        })
    },
};
```

It still won't work even if I change `.addNumberOption` into `.addStringOption` and parse `serverPort` into an integer using `parseInt(serverPort)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that you pass an object as the second parameter here: `util.status(server, { port: serverPort })` while it [should be the port number](https://passthemayo.gitbook.io/minecraft-server-util/api/java-server-status):

```js
return util.status(server, serverPort)
```

Another thing, `serverPort == NaN` is always `false`. Even `NaN == NaN` is `false`. You should use `isNaN` instead:

```js
let serverPort = NaN

console.log(serverPort == NaN)
console.log(serverPort === NaN)
console.log(isNaN(serverPort))
```

Although I'm not sure if it's ever `NaN`, as `getNumber()` returns the value of the option, or `null` if not set and not required.

Comment: I replaced `util.status(server, { port: parseInt(serverPort)})` into `util.status(server, serverPort)` but I a new error appeared:

```
C:\Users\Dell 9030 AIO\OneDrive\Desktop\updated discord bot\node_modules\minecraft-server-util\dist\status.js:42
            reject(new Error('Timed out while retrieving server status'));
```

Comment: Have you tried to increase the `timeout` option? What's the server and port number?

Comment: I haven't tried any options yet, I've tried just straight up putting the server address and port in the parameters (`util.status(2b2t.org, 25565)`) but the `"Timed out while retrieving server status"` error still shows up.

Comment: This error only shows up in this version of discord.js (v13) as my bot in v12 didn't have this error.

Comment: I've just tested it using v13 slash commands on my computer and it works as expected when I use `util.status(server, serverPort)` and type `2b2t.org` and `25565` after the slash command (`"minecraft-server-util": "^5.2.9"`, `"discord.js": "^13.5.1"`)

Comment: my discord.js version is 13.6.0

Comment: I'll try hosting it on heroku and see if the error still appears

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it has something to do with my PC because when I hosted it on Heroku, it seems to have worked. `util.status(server, serverPort)` seems to work better than { port: parseInt(serverPort) }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Does it work with the original `{ port: parseInt(serverPort)}` or did my answer help you?

Comment: it works with `util.status(server, serverPort)` and if the internet is slow it doesn't work